# react Компонент с таймером не обновляется таймер

Tags: reactjs

Делаю компонент с таймером, но он добавляет к таймеру всего +1 и больше не работает, из за чего это может быть и как можно исправить?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const TimerPages = ( { updateTime, stopTimer, resetTimers}) => {

    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
    const [resetTimer, setResetTimer] = useState(false);

    const addTimer = () => {
        setTimer(timer + 1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            addTimer()
        }
        , 1000)}, [])


    useEffect(() => {
        updateTime(timer);
    }, [timer]}) 




    return (
        <h5 className='card-title'>Время игры: {timer}</h5>
    );
};

export default TimerPages;
```

Comment: Вы совершаете ту же ошибку что и в прошлый раз. Вам надо основательно прочитать [эту часть статьи](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) и прочитать в целом саму статью тоже надо. Вы не понимаете как работает массив зависимостей

Comment: я думал, я этим способом просто запущу вызов функции каждую секунду

Comment: а вот теперь когда я сбрасываю таймер, его начинаеть двоить, троить и т.д в зависимости от кол ва изменений

Comment: Так оно и происходит, вы вызваете его каждую секунду. Ладно я немного погорячился, вам начинающему это скорее всего вообще не очевидно)) Как дойду домой напишу ответ (если меня не опередят). Но в целом суть в том что хоть ф-ия и отрабатывает каждую секунду, компонента не перерисовывается

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-shape-7cj8bs?file=/src/App.js
Вроде могу поделится проектом. Там если 20 сек подождать, то будет видно как таймеру плохо.
Это мой самый первый проект. После кликера, в котором я просто смотрел как всё работает

Comment: да не совсем очевидно. Когда я без useEffect юзал setInterval, то почти всё хорошо было. По крайне мере, он каждую секунду отрабатывал, а как только useEffect использовал, то он только 1 раз отрисовал, а потом просто прибавлял без отрисовки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так самое важное тут - это понять, что компонента перерисовывается только при обновлении стейта ([Как оказалось это не совсем правда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883745/react-component-sometimes-renders-twice-with-unchanged-state)). В этом случае (упрощённом естественно) всего один стейт - это `timer`

- В первый раз компонента рендерится со стейтом 0 и мы видим в консоли `Render`
- Потом запускается `useEffect`, в консоли видим `Use effect` и устанавливает бесконечный таймер. Тут очень важно понять, что функция в `setInterval` **ВСЕГДА** будет видеть только те значения стейта, при которых он был вызван. В конкретном случае это значит, что при инициализации `timer === 0`, потому после ререндеринга, когда в `timer` будет новое значение, наша функция `addTimer` не будет об этом знать
- Через время запускается `addTimer`, мы в консоли видим `timer 0` и устанавливаем новое значение равное `timer + 1`. И так у нас до обновления `timer === 0`, потому когда мы вставим новое значение т.е. `0 + 1 = 1`, то стейт обновится, произойдёт перерисовка и мы увидим в консоли `Render`
- Опять через время запускается `addTimer`, мы в консоли видим `timer 0` и устанавливаем значение равное `timer + 1`, НО помним что в нашей функции `timer` всегда равен 0, потому мы опять будем пытаться вставить значение 1. Предыдущее значение было 1 и мы опять пытаемся вставить 1, потому обновлении стейта не произойдёт. Тут нужна оговорка хоть мы и увидим в третий раз `Render` - это не потому что обновилось значение, а просто React не гаранитрует, что не перерисует при одном и том же значении стейта
- Дальше мы бесконечно будем видеть в консоли `timer 0`, потому что мы постоянно будем пытаться обновить значение с 1 на 1, React увидит, что новое значение равно предыдущему и не будет перерисовывать, потому `Render` в консоли мы больше не увидим

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const App = () => {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  const addTimer = () => {
    console.log('timer', timer);
    
    setTimer(timer + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Use effect');
  
    setInterval(addTimer, 4000);
  }, [])


  return <h5 className='card-title'> Время игры: {console.log('Render') || timer}</h5>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Если не хотите ждать, то вот какой вывод консоли будет:

```
Render
Use effect
timer 0
Render
timer 0
Render - этот рендер не связан с тем что состояние обновилось
timer 0 (бесконечно раз)
```

Что очень важно при работе с таймерами - это всегда них очищать, как только они больше не нужны. Есть несколько решений этой проблемы:

1. Как по мне самое лучшее - это заменить `setInterval` на `setTimeout` и в массив зависимостей вставить `timer`. Так мы всегда будем получать новое значение стейта и будем устанавливать таймер только после того как обновится компонента в отлии от `setInterval`, который насильно будет вызывать функцию

   ```js
   const {useEffect, useState} = React;

   const App = () => {

     const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

     const addTimer = () => {    
       setTimer(timer + 1);
     }

     useEffect(() => {
       const timeout = setTimeout(addTimer, 1000);
       
       return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
     }, [timer])


     return <h5 className='card-title'> Время игры: {timer}</h5>;
   };

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="root"></div>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Можно вызывать не просто `addTimer(timer + 1)`, а вызывать `addTimer(t => t + 1)`. В этом случае нам не важно что в переменной `timer`, мы смотрим на текущее состояние стейта, которое приходит на вход в `t`, потому всё будет работать корректно

   ```js
   const {useEffect, useState} = React;

   const App = () => {

     const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

     const addTimer = () => {    
       setTimer(t => t + 1);
     }

     useEffect(() => {
       const interval = setInterval(addTimer, 1000);
       
       return () => clearInterval(interval);
     }, [])


     return <h5 className='card-title'> Время игры: {timer}</h5>;
   };

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="root"></div>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: можете ещё раз помочь? https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sammet-ponl2x?file=/src/components/ItemContainer.tsx
Не знаю как детально описать, но. Данные с сервера спокойно приходят, но после попытки вставить данные в ItemCard в файле ItemContainer, то ничего не происходит, из за чего и как можно исправить?

Comment: @Merka Спросите лучше как отдельный вопрос, но подозреваю, что вам в `items` приходит `undefined`